# str_replace_all only getting first

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to make a function to rename all the columns of a `data.frame` into snake case. Here's an example:

```
tibble("DateOfDeath" = NA,
       "Death" = NA,
       "Operative_Death" = NA) %>% 
  rename_all(function(x){str_replace_all(string = x, 
                                         pattern = '([[:alnum:]])([[:upper:]])([[:lower:]])', 
                                         replacement = '\\1_\\2\\3')}) %>% 
  rename_all(tolower)
```

I can't quite figure out why I'm getting 'date_ofdeath' instead of 'date_of_death'. It looks like there is another series of alphanumeric, upper case, and lowercase left in the string but `str_replace_all` doesn't catch it.

Thanks!

Comment: The lower from the first match is overlapping with the alnum from the second match.  I think you should use the snakecase library like in the answer.

Comment: `replacement = '\\1_\\2\\3_'`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I don't think that will work if the intermediary words are longer than 2 characters.

Comment: You should present a larger dataset to accommodate the input which you expect to encounter and point out where your regex fails and what you expect as the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `snakecase` library, which was basically made for things like this:

```
tibble("DateOfDeath" = NA,
       "Death" = NA,
       "Operative_Death" = NA) %>%
 rename_all(to_snake_case)

  date_of_death death operative_death
  <lgl>         <lgl> <lgl>          
1 NA            NA    NA
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It solves my problem but doesn't answer my question ;)